# how to install conda install scikits.talkbox package in Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, visual-c++-2010

I am trying to install scikits.talkbox but in command prompt It is giving me error messages (error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools")